Use vert.x RecordParser with WebClient streaming
I am trying to use RecordParser for large response from WebClient.
Vert.x documentation says:

When large response are expected, use the BodyCodec.pipe. This body
codec pumps the response body buffers to a WriteStream and signals the
success or the failure of the operation in the async result response

But I don't see an easy way to pass that WriteStream to RecordParser. I have used simplified code pasted below which works but implementing such is a source of potential bugs as async protocols are easier to mess up. Does vert.x offers out of box such integration.
RecordParser parser = RecordParser.newDelimited("\n", b -> log.info("r={}", b.toString()));
RecordParserWriteStream bridge = new RecordParserWriteStream(parser);
client
    .get(sut.actualPort(), "localhost", "/stream?file=stream2.txt")
    .as(BodyCodec.pipe(bridge))
    .send(
        ar -> {
          if (ar.succeeded()) {
            ctx.completeNow();
          } else {
            ctx.failNow(ar.cause());
          }
        });


@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RecordParserWriteStream implements WriteStream<Buffer> {

    private final RecordParser recordParser;

    @Override
    public WriteStream<Buffer> exceptionHandler(@Nullable Handler<Throwable> handler) {
        recordParser.exceptionHandler(handler);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Buffer data, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> handler) {
        log.info("write {}", data.length());
        recordParser.handle(data);
        Promise<Void> promise = Promise.promise();
        promise.complete();
        handler.handle(promise.future());
    }

    @Override
    public void end(Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> handler) {
        Promise<Void> promise = Promise.promise();
        promise.complete();
        handler.handle(promise.future());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean writeQueueFull() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public WriteStream<Buffer> drainHandler(@Nullable Handler<Void> handler) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Future<Void> write(Buffer data) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public WriteStream<Buffer> setWriteQueueMaxSize(int maxSize) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

I found few older SO answers where it was suggested to use HttpClient but official documentation still recommends WebClient with BodyCodec.pipe/WriteStream.
With using HttpClient it looks as
RecordParser parser = RecordParser.newDelimited("\n", h -> log.info("r={}", h.toString()));
client
    .request(HttpMethod.GET, sut.actualPort(), "localhost", "/stream?file=stream1.txt")
    .compose(HttpClientRequest::send)
    .onComplete(
        ar -> {
          if (ar.succeeded()) {
            HttpClientResponse response = ar.result();
            response.handler(parser);
            response.endHandler(e -> ctx.completeNow());
          } else {
            ctx.failNow(ar.cause());
          }
        });

What is a best way to call HTTP service and pass the response to RecordParser?

This question is similar to: Vert.x httpClient/webClient process response chunk by chunk or as stream. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
